# Перегрузка метода абстрактного класса

Tags: c++

Не знаю правильно ли я назвал вопрос, но ситуация такая. Есть класс Parent:

```
class Parent {
   virtual void m(int a);
   virtual void m(int a, int b);
};
```

и классы-дети:

```
class Child_one : public Parent {
   void m(int a);
};

class Child_two : public Parent {
   void m(int a, int b);
};
```

И, собственно, как быть в таких случаях? Компилятор требует реализацию обоих перегрузок `m(...)` в каждом ребенке.

Comment: Ну так реализуете, в чем проблема?

Comment: Но они там не нужны. `m` разный для `Child_one` и `Child_two`. Для первого ребенка достаточно одного параметра `int`. Для второго - двух.

Хотя сейчас подумал. Можно дефолтные значения выставить.

Comment: Если у вас нет очевидного способа реализовать абстрактные методы родительского класса, может быть, вы неправильно выстроили иерархию наследования?

Comment: @VladD, Этот попрос - продолжение http://hashcode.ru/questions/382601. Вот там я реализовывал иерархию наследования для фигур. Смотрите, есть абстрактный класс - фигура. От неё унаследованы разные фигуры. В том числе точка, линия, окружность, эллипс. И есть метод `move()` который в качестве параметров принимает дельту `x` и `y` для точки, дельту Point'ы `start` и `end` для прямой и так далее. Соответственно move для каждого свой. И реализовывать 6 move'ов в каждом наследнике неправильно, а значит виртуальный метод `move` для Shape не сделаешь.Как нужно было реализовывать иерархию наследования

Comment: дефолтные значения для параметров выглядят как костыль. Просто вам не нужны оба этих виртуальных метода в классе Parent, раз каждый из них не нужен в каком-то из наследников. 

Вероятно, классы-наследники должны наследоваться каждый от своего абстрактного класса (ну или от своего интерфейса, которых, впрочем, в С++ насколько знаю, нет)

Comment: @ssh: Ага, всё проясняется. Тогда может быть вам не стоит объявлять метод `move` абстрактным. Если список аргументов зависит от типа, вам всё равно придётся выяснять настоящий тип перед вызовом.

Comment: @ssh: Или может вам нужен лишь абстрактный метод `move` с параметрами `double dx, double dy`? И может быть другие неабстрактные `move` в конкретных классах.

Comment: @VladD, нет, абстрактный move(float, float) не нужен. А вот насчет неабстрактных move в детях, может быть и подходит. Но сработает ли? Создаваться то будет `Shape` а там move нет

Comment: @ssh: `Shape` по существу создаваться не будет — экземпляр абстрактного класса создать невозможно. Вы сможете создать лишь конкретный `Line`, `Point` и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По стандарту языка чистый виртуальный класс должен содержать только общие методы, которые в последствии будут полностью реализованы. Продумайте лучше вашу архитектуру по совету [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd).